# How to get all methods in MEF

Tags: c#, mef

I have attribute class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MethodGetterAttribute : ExportAttribute
{

}
```

I'm using it in method of several namespaces:

```
namespace Model.First
{
    public class PersonBL
    {
        [MethodGetter]
        public void GetName(Person person)
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace Model.First.Second
{
    public class PersonBL
    {
        [MethodGetter]
        public void GetName(Person person)
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace Model.First.Second.Third
{
    public class WorkerBL
    {
        [MethodGetter]
        public void GetName(Worker worker)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want to order all methods and run it one by one. To get methods I'm doing this:

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(assemblies.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetName().Name.Contains("Model"))));
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
var importedMethods = container.GetExports<Action<Worker>>() as IEnumerable<Lazy<Action<Worker>>>;
var result = importedMethods.Select(a => a.Value.Target).ToList();// Here i'm getting only worker's method
```

But it returns only Worker's method. How can I get all three methods from worker?

Comment: Are worker and person in any relation?

Comment: @Alex Yep, Worker inherits from Person

Comment: Are you looking for all methods with your attribute and particular signature? In your code all methods with the attribute are of the same signature. (About the same considering inheritance.)

Comment: So why do you specify ```Worker``` here ```var importedMethods = container.GetExports<Action<Worker>>()```?

Comment: @Alex Sorry, "I'm looking for all methods with my attribute and particular signature" that's what I wanted to say

Comment: ```GetExports<Action<Worker>>()``` means you are looking for ```void(Worker)```. There is only one method and it is ```void WorkerBL.(Worker worker)```. That's why you get such a result.

Comment: Worker is inherited from Person. I can do worker.ParentMethod(). Can I get methods of parent from child or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192100/discussion-between-alex-and-dilshod).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...
Let's create  4 class libraries

Zero.dll with all classes used in other assemblies

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Zero
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class MethodGetterAttribute : ExportAttribute { }

    public class Person { }

    public class Worker : Person { }

    public static class MethodHelper
    {
        public static string GetMethod()
        {
            var method = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
            return $"{method.DeclaringType.FullName} {method}";
        }
    }

    public static class Discovery
    {
        public static TDelegate[] GetDelegates<TAttribure, TDelegate>()
            where TAttribure : Attribute
            where TDelegate : Delegate
        {
            return Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "*.dll")
                            .Select(file => { try { return Assembly.LoadFrom(file); } catch { return null; } })
                            .OfType<Assembly>()
                            .Append(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())
                            .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                            .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
                            .Where(method => method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribure)).Any())
                            .Select(method => Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TDelegate), null, method, false))
                            .OfType<TDelegate>()
                            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Model.First.dll referencing Zero.dll

```
using System;
using Zero;

namespace Model.First
{
    public class PersonBL
    {
        [MethodGetter]
        public void GetName(Person person)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MethodHelper.GetMethod());
        }
    }
}
```

Model.First.Second.dll referencing Zero.dll

```
using System;
using Zero;

namespace Model.First.Second
{
    public class PersonBL
    {
        [MethodGetter]
        public void GetName(Person person)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MethodHelper.GetMethod());
        }

        [MethodGetter]
        public void Incompatible(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MethodHelper.GetMethod());
        }
    }
}
```

Model.First.Second.Third.dll referencing Zero.dll

```
using System;
using Zero;

namespace Model.First.Second.Third
{
    public class WorkerBL
    {
        [MethodGetter]
        public void GetName(Worker worker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MethodHelper.GetMethod());
        }

        public void NoAttribute(Worker worker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MethodHelper.GetMethod());
        }
    }
}
```

Then let's create console application ConsoleApp.exe referencing Zero.dll, Model.First.dll, Model.First.Second.dll and Model.First.Second.Third.dll

```
using System;
using Zero;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var worker = new Worker();
            foreach (var d in Discovery.GetDelegates<MethodGetterAttribute, Action<Worker>>())
                d.Invoke(worker);
        }        
    }

    public class WorkerBL
    {
        [MethodGetter]
        public void GetName(Worker worker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MethodHelper.GetMethod());
        }
    }
}
```

Let's create Junk.txt, put some nonsense like `bd%E56#EVwD` into it, rename the file to Junk.dll and add it into .exe file directory and then start the application.

Output is:

```
Model.First.PersonBL Void GetName(Zero.Person)
Model.First.Second.PersonBL Void GetName(Zero.Person)
Model.First.Second.Third.WorkerBL Void GetName(Zero.Worker)
ConsoleApp.WorkerBL Void GetName(Zero.Worker)
```

As expected. It finds all compatible methods with specified attribute and returns delegates for them.