# See if MemberInfo matches BindingFlags using C#

Tags: c#, reflection, bindingflags

I need to see if a `MemberInfo` matches a particular `BindingFlags`. The closest method to this is `Type#GetMember(string, BindingFlags)`.

I cannot find any method to do this.

I want to do something like this:

```
private List<MemberInfo> _members;

public IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetMembers(BindingFlags flags)
{
    foreach(var member in _members)
    {
        if(member.MatchesFlags(flags))
        {
             yield return member;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Chicken-and-egg, you first need to fill the members list and that requires using BindingFlags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual types of `MemberInfo` obtained with reflection (e.g. via calling `MemberInfo[] 
GetMembers()` on `Type`) are:

- `System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo`
- `System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo`
- `System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo`
- `System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo`

All of them **independently** have property `BindingFlags` of type `BindingFlags`. But the property is **NonPublic**. And the types are `internal sealed`, that makes them **inaccessible** in normal code. Here `reflection` comes to rescue. To get `BindingFlags` of a `MemberInfo` one can use such an extension:

```
public static class MemberInfoExtension
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<MemberInfo, BindingFlags> cache =
        new Dictionary<MemberInfo, BindingFlags>();
    private static readonly BindingFlags flags =
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

    public static BindingFlags GetFlags(this MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        if (cache.TryGetValue(memberInfo, out var bindingFlags))
            return bindingFlags;

        return cache[memberInfo] =
            (BindingFlags)memberInfo.GetType()
                                    .GetProperty("BindingFlags", flags)
                                    .GetValue(memberInfo);
    }
}
```

To find matches with `BindingFlags` the following helper methods can be used:

```
public static class BindingFlagsExtension
{
    public static bool Contains(this BindingFlags flags, BindingFlags bindingFlags) =>
        (flags & bindingFlags) == bindingFlags;

    public static bool MatchesExactly(this BindingFlags flags, BindingFlags bindingFlags) =>
        flags == bindingFlags;

    public static bool MatchesPartly(this BindingFlags flags, BindingFlags bindingFlags) =>
        (flags & bindingFlags) != 0;
}
```

To test the solution one can use a class like this:

```
private class DemoClass
{
    private int PrivateInstanceField;
    public string PublicInstanceField;
    private bool PrivateInstanceProperty { get; }
    public object PublicInstanceProperty { get; }
    private void PrivateInstanceMethod() { }
    public void PublicInstanceMethod() { }
    private static int PrivateStaticField;
    public static string PublicStaticField;
    private static bool PrivateStaticProperty { get; }
    public static object PublicStaticProperty { get; }
    private static void PrivateStaticMethod() { }
    public static void PublicStaticMethod() { }
}
```

Then running:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var type = typeof(DemoClass);
    var members = type.GetMembers();
    var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

    Console.WriteLine($"{type.Name} members with flags containing: {flags}\n");
    foreach (var m in members.Where(m => m.GetFlags().Contains(flags)))
        Print(m);

    Console.WriteLine($"\n{type.Name} members with flags matching exactly: {flags}\n");
    foreach (var m in members.Where(m => m.GetFlags().MatchesExactly(flags)))
        Print(m);

    Console.WriteLine($"\n{type.Name} members with flags matching partly: {flags}\n");
    foreach (var m in members.Where(m => m.GetFlags().MatchesPartly(flags)))
        Print(m);
}

private static void Print(MemberInfo memberInfo) =>
    Console.WriteLine($"\t{memberInfo.GetType().Name} {memberInfo} - {memberInfo.GetFlags()}");
```

gives:

```
DemoClass members with flags containing: Instance, Public

        RuntimeMethodInfo System.Object get_PublicInstanceProperty() - Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo Void PublicInstanceMethod() - Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo Boolean Equals(System.Object) - DeclaredOnly, Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo Int32 GetHashCode() - DeclaredOnly, Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo System.Type GetType() - DeclaredOnly, Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo System.String ToString() - DeclaredOnly, Instance, Public
        RuntimeConstructorInfo Void .ctor() - Instance, Public
        RuntimePropertyInfo System.Object PublicInstanceProperty - Instance, Public
        RtFieldInfo System.String PublicInstanceField - Instance, Public

DemoClass members with flags matching exactly: Instance, Public

        RuntimeMethodInfo System.Object get_PublicInstanceProperty() - Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo Void PublicInstanceMethod() - Instance, Public
        RuntimeConstructorInfo Void .ctor() - Instance, Public
        RuntimePropertyInfo System.Object PublicInstanceProperty - Instance, Public
        RtFieldInfo System.String PublicInstanceField - Instance, Public

DemoClass members with flags matching partly: Instance, Public

        RuntimeMethodInfo System.Object get_PublicInstanceProperty() - Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo Void PublicInstanceMethod() - Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo System.Object get_PublicStaticProperty() - Static, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo Void PublicStaticMethod() - Static, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo Boolean Equals(System.Object) - DeclaredOnly, Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo Int32 GetHashCode() - DeclaredOnly, Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo System.Type GetType() - DeclaredOnly, Instance, Public
        RuntimeMethodInfo System.String ToString() - DeclaredOnly, Instance, Public
        RuntimeConstructorInfo Void .ctor() - Instance, Public
        RuntimePropertyInfo System.Object PublicInstanceProperty - Instance, Public
        RuntimePropertyInfo System.Object PublicStaticProperty - Static, Public
        RtFieldInfo System.String PublicInstanceField - Instance, Public
        RtFieldInfo System.String PublicStaticField - Static, Public
```

Comment: The idea of using reflection to gain internal information about types returned from reflection amuses me. It's Reflection-Inception!

Comment: @Bradley Uffner, yes! Using reflection and IL is a way to unimaginable things, I believe,)

Comment: @Bradley Uffner, if you are interested take a look at the following posts.
They are objects of my proud.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55954016/detect-source-language-at-runtime-from-within-debugging-visualizer/56006175#56006175

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757595/how-to-get-all-methods-in-mef/55767958#55767958

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55216204/get-the-original-name-of-a-variable-passed-as-a-parameter/55230542#55230542